# Is there a way to get complete tasks from JBPM 7 using its REST API

Tags: rest, process, jbpm

I'm trying to get a complete process instance tasks but in vain.

The REST service `/server/containers/{containerId}/processes/instances/{processInstanceId}` return only active user tasks. I read swagger documentation and couldn't find any service doing the job.

Please tell me if you had already this problem and how did you resolve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the description; what I want is to be able to get details of complete processes tasks. The solution I found is to call the REST service

`GET /server/containers/{containerId}/processes/instances/{processInstanceId}/nodes/instances`

Which return informaions of all the process nodes including tasks ones.

Answer (score 0):

by default, tasks are removed once the process is completed. There is a property "org.jbpm.task.cleanup.enabled" that you can tweak, setting to false will make tasks to remain there after its process completion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually this property is set to false. The complete tasks remain on jBPM Business Central but I don't know how to get them via jBPM Rest API.

Answer (score 0):

I did what [Abhijit Humbe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64851350/11536684) answered, I go to installation folder,

Wildfly > Standalone > Configuration

Edited the files standalone.xml and standalone-full.xml

Inside properties, added the below property:

```
<property name="org.jbpm.task.cleanup.enabled" value="false"/>
```

Stop jBPM and start again. By doing this, jBPM no longer deletes tasks details after process completion.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).